# srand is causing my program to freeze

Tags: c++, encryption, rsa, srand

I have implemented the RSA algorithm in C++, the program is working however the srand calls are making the program slow. I have used srand for generating the two prime numbers and the encryption key (e). Here's the snippet

```
...............................................
do
{
    p = make_prime_number();
    q = make_prime_number();
}while(p == q);

phi = (p - 1) * (q - 1);
n = p * q;

do
{
    e = random_builder (20);

    int *t = extended_gcd (e, phi);
    d = t[0];
}while(gcd(e, phi) != 1 || d < 1 || d >= n );
...............................................

int random_builder(const int max)
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    return rand() % max + 1;
}

bool is_prime(const int num)
{
    for(int i = 2; i <= num/2; i++)
        if(num % i == 0) 
            return false;

    return true;
}

int make_prime_number()
{
    int num;

    do
    {
        num = random_builder(20);
    }while(not is_prime(num));

    return num;
}
```

Can we somehow speed up the process by modifying the seed in srand ?

Comment: You should only call `srand` once at the beginning of your program.

Comment: Note that the `srand()` and `rand()` combination are not guaranteed to be 'cryptographically random'; in fact, they are practically guaranteed not to be suitable for use in cryptography.  For toy programs, it won't matter; for real programs, it will matter intensely (especially as using `time(0)` is not remotely random as a seed for `srand()`).

Comment: @killogre mersenne twister is **not** a cryptographic PRNG. It's good enough for simulations, but sucks for crypto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to call `srand()` more than once. Call it *once* at the start of your program, and then leave it alone.

After calling `srand()` with a specific seed value, the *same* sequence of random numbers is generated by `rand()`. Therefore, since you are calling with the current time in *seconds*, your `random_builder()` function only returns a different value once every **second**.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `rand()` or `srand` at all. You should use a well seeded cryptographic PRNG. On linux you can simply read from `/dev/urandom` and on windows you can use `CryptGenRandom`.